# Availability of data from 3 specific FDA web pages

Tags: api, openfda

I'm looking at the API references for drugs and for devices, but haven't found answers. I'm wondering if it is possible to return the information that is listed on 3 web pages at FDA:

1. Hematology/Oncology (Cancer) Approvals & Safety Notifications (https://www.fda.gov/Drugs/InformationOnDrugs/ApprovedDrugs/ucm279174.htm), specifically the approval status, indication, drug name
2. List of Cleared or Approved Companion Diagnostic Devices (https://www.fda.gov/MedicalDevices/ProductsandMedicalProcedures/InVitroDiagnostics/ucm301431.htm) specifically the drug name, device trade name, manufacturer, intended use/indications
3. Also from Medical Devices (ucm330711): Nucleic Acid Based Tests - specifically disease name, trade name, test manufacturer

I don't want to screen scrape; openFDA JSON file returns are perfect.

If these can be pulled from openFDA data, could you point me to the reference information that will enable me to accomplish these data requests?

Answer (score 1):

The lists on the three referenced pages are not available (as is) through an openFDA API. However, you can find some of the information on these page in openFDA.

You can find information on the cleared or approved companion devices (in #2) by searching on PMA_number. For example: https://api.fda.gov/device/pma.json?search=pma_number:P170005

You can find information on cleared or approved nucleic acid based tests (in #3) by searching on k_number. For example: https://api.fda.gov/device/510k.json?search=k_number:K070804

Hope this helps.